# Clear all bookmarks from Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently, I can add bookmarks on Itellij by the shortcut key `ctrl`+`f11`. For removing that bookmark, I need to go to that line and press the same shortcut key. Now I want to delete all bookmarks at once without removing them one by one.

How do I remove all bookmarks from Intellij? Is there any shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207013335-Clear-all-bookmarks-):

> Shift+F11 (Show bookmarks), select all bookmarks with Shift, hit Delete.